# Javascript won't display variable

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to calculate the number of days between 08/28/2011 and the current date.
For some reason, the document.write line isn't doing anything.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    var firstDate = new Date(2011,08,28);
    var secondDate = new Date(year,month,day);
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    document.write(diffdays);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. `diffdays` is a completely separate variable from `diffDays`.

In future, you should check your browser's Console (in IE and Chrome, press F12 and find the Console tab), as here you will see an error message and you would have caught your mistake.

Comment: F12 also works in FireFox... +1 for "_use a debugger before asking questions like this!!_"

Comment: @jahroy I wasn't aware of that - last I knew you had to press some awkward combination of Ctrl, Alt and some letter I can't remember. Have they brought back "F6 focuses the address bar" yet?

Comment: `CTRL-SHIFT-C` is the same as clicking "_inspect element_" in FireBug.  `F12` brings up FireBug... so, actually, you were probably correct and I was wrong by assuming the user has FireBug installed.

Comment: I didn't know about `F6`, but it does work on the latest FireFox.  I always use `ALT-D` for that (or `CTRL-L`).

Comment: Yeah, without FireBug it's really annoying to debug anything XD It's sad you need an extension just to do basic things... Anyways, F6 has been the standard shortcut for that for ages, then they changed it in FF4 for no reason at all. That was when I stopped caring about that browser :P

Comment: `CTRL-L` works on the _big four_ browsers on the _big three_ operating systems... Glad to hear there are others as stubborn as me about shortcuts and features!  I won't switch to Chrome until they add "_Search while typing_" (without needing an extension).

Comment: "Search while typing"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: In Firefox it's a basic setting to enable "_Search for text when I start typing_", which searches the current web page for text as soon as you start to type.  For whatever reason, the lack of this feature in Chrome is a show-stopper for me.  In Chrome you have to hit `CTRL-F` before typing... which sounds very easy, but I cannot overcome the inconvenience compared to FireFox.

Comment: Hmm... Well since Ctrl+F is standard in Notepad and other programs that involve text, I don't really mind that.

Comment: I never said it was a rational hangup!  Once you get used to it, it's hard to live without, tho...

Answer (score 3):

It should be diffDays and not diffdays. JS is case sensitive.